# Tangent vector of curve $ \Psi(t)= (2t^3 - 2t, 4t^2, t^3+t )^T $ expressed in spherical coordinates

Tags: proof-verification, curves, spherical-coordinates, line-integrals

I have a curve where $ t\in R^{+}_0$

$$
 \Psi(t)=  (2t^3 - 2t, 4t^2, t^3+t )^T
 $$

I need to express tangent vector T in standard spherical coordinates in terms of normalized 'frame vectors' $\hat h_i $.

I started from denoting spherical cordinates and comparing with the given data  $$x=r \sin\Phi \cos\lambda=2t^3 - 2t=2t(t^2-1)$$
$$y=r \sin\Phi \sin\lambda=4t^2$$
$$z=r \cos\Phi=t^3+t=t(t+1) $$

Tangent vector is defined as:
$$T=\dot r |h_r| \hat h_r +\dot \phi |h_\phi| \hat h_\phi +\dot \lambda |h_\lambda| \hat h_\lambda $$

I don't know how to determine $r, \phi, \lambda$. Any tips?

Comment: Why do you not compute tangent vector before converting to spherical coordinates?

Comment: I don't know how to solve this task. That was my the only idea of starting from conversion. How can I do it in the way you proposed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
  \mathbf{r} &=
  \begin{pmatrix} 2t^3-2t \\ 4t^2 \\ t^3+t \end{pmatrix} \\
  r &= \sqrt{(2t^3-2t)^2+(4t^2)^2+(t^3+t)^2} \\
  &= t(t^2+1)\sqrt{5} \tag{$t>0$} \\
  \dot{r} &= (3t^2+1)\sqrt{5} \\
  \cos \theta &= \frac{z}{r} \\
  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \\
  \sin \theta &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \\
  \dot{\theta} &= 0 \\
  \tan \phi &= \frac{y}{x} \\
  \phi &= \tan^{-1} \frac{2t}{t^2-1} \\
  \dot{\phi} &= -\frac{2}{t^2+1} \\
  \mathbf{v} &=
  \dot{r} \, \mathbf{e}_r+
  r\dot{\theta} \, \mathbf{e}_{\theta}+
  r\dot{\phi} \sin \theta \, \mathbf{e}_{\phi} \\
  &= \sqrt{5}(3t^2+1) \, \mathbf{e}_r-4t\, \mathbf{e}_{\phi} \\
  \mathbf{T} &=
  \frac{(3t^2+1)\sqrt{5} \, \mathbf{e}_r-
  4t\, \mathbf{e}_{\phi}}{\sqrt{45t^4+46t^2+5}}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you @Ng Chung Tak! I was trying figure out how did you form $v$ and $T$ equation but I don't understand it. Could you please explain it?

Comment: Please see [**spherical polar coordinates**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Kinematics) and by definition $\mathbf{T}=\dfrac{\mathbf{v}}{v}$